# 100% width on an absolute positioned image

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is 50% the width of the screen and 100% height.

I want to have an image placed at the bottom of the div that will adjust with the width.

To set the position I use position: absolute; but this removed the auto width:

code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#full-size {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#aaaaa {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0F0;
  float: left;
}

.bottomImage {
  width: auto !important;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="full-size" class="clearfix">

  <div id="aaaaa">
    <img class="bottomImage" src="events_bottom.png" />
  </div>


</div>
```

Is there any way to have an image positioned absolute and adjust to container width?

Comment: It probably doesn't help you're trying to declare the width 3 times...

Comment: That wouldn't change anything

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses! Position:relative on the parent and left and right done it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
.aaaaa {
position: relative;
}

.bottomImage {    
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1oxy7odv/

Answer (score 4):

Adding `position: relative` to `#aaaaa` allows the image width and offsets to be computed with respect to the `#aaaaa` block's width and position.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#full-size {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#aaaaa {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0F0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.bottomImage {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="full-size" class="clearfix">
  <div id="aaaaa">
    <img class="bottomImage" src="http://placehold.it/300x50" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: black;
    margin: 50px auto;}

img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    height: 25px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use another positioning for your bottomImage to size with its parent container:

```
.bottomImage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; //or whatever position from top
    left: 0;
    right: 0; //important !!! this way its always on the rightest(?) position of the parent)
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
.bottomImage {
    width: inherit; /*inherits width from div.aaaaa*/
    max-width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```